# Get value of .htaccess RewriteBase param in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm wondering if there is a method in PHP for getting the values of specific rules set out in a .htaccess file? In basic terms: if there is a (for example) `RewiteBase` rule, what is it's value?

There does not seem to be anything to serve this in the Manual for `$_SERVER`, perhaps `fread()`?

Comment: I'm trying to adapt to a potentially dynamic enviroment. Knowing what access rules have been set would be useful to me. I will probably end up just reading the content, as you say

Comment: I'm attempting a small CMS, which could be installed either at the root, or in a sub directory. If installed in a subdirectory, the RewriteBase rule (amirite in calling it a rule?) would define that portion of the url - which I can then discount when parsing said url.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope there is no way to retrieve it.

`RewriteBase` itself is not a rule, it is just a string that will be cut off the url before rewriting process.

So php just doesn't have any chances to retrieve it

PS: personally I cannot think of any reason to rely on its value. Probably you're trying to solve some issue in a wrong way.

PPS: I put answer to the @Adi's question from the comments here:

It is not possible to just read the `.htaccess` because of:

1. There might be several `.htaccess` files in different directories and you cannot be sure which one has been used
2. `RewriteCond` can be specified in `httpd.conf`

Comment: @Adnan Shammout: answered to your question in my answer's PPS

Comment: It seems your answer is the right one, even though my problem remains :/ Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of doing this?

Note that you can set `ENV` variable through `.htaccess` as well as `php_flag`/`php_value`.

If this is not an option, you may obviously read the file content and doing sort of grep.

`file_get_content('.htaccess');` should do the trick.